# How to make footable work with handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, footable

The code I am working with is using handlebar.js to create tables. Now I want to make it responsive using footable. However, footable does not work... probably it does not recognize the table headers inside script tag.

My code looks like this

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: auto; max-height: auto">
<table class="table table-striped provReportsTable footable toggle-medium">

    <script id="provider_reports_templ" type="x-handlebars-template">
<tr>
    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Bill No.</th>
    <th data-toggle="true">Patient Name</th>
    <th>Paid Amount</th>
    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Payment Date</th>
    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Payment Mode</th>
    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Claim ID</th>
    <th data-hide="phone,tablet"></th>
</tr>
```

{{#each this}}

```
<tr id="initialRow{{ count }}" attr="{{ count }}" class="initialRow">
    <td> {{ BillNumber }} </td>
    <td class="blue"> {{ Name }} </td>
    <td>{{ Currency }}{{ Amount }}</td>
    <td> {{ PaymentDate }} </td>
    <td> {{ PaymentMode }} </td>
    <td> {{ClaimID}} </td>
    <td>
        <span class="actionbox view" title="View"><span class="Icon viewIcon"></span></span>
        <span class="actionbox print" title="Print"><span class="Icon printIcon"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="detailRow{{ count }}" attr="{{ count }}" class="detailRow">
    <td> {{ BillNumber }} </td>
    <td class="blue">
        {{ Name}}
    </td>
    <td>${{ Amount }}</td>
    <td> {{ PaymentDate }} </td>
    <td> {{ PaymentMode}} </td>
    <td> {{ClaimID}} </td>
    <td>
        <span class="actionbox view" title="View"><span class="Icon viewIcon"></span><span class="Icontxt">View</span></span><br />
        <span class="actionbox print" title="Print"><span class="Icon printIcon"></span><span class="Icontxt">Print</span></span><br />
    </td>
</tr>
```

{{/each}}

Comment: Can you post the JS that initializes the table render and footable?
It won't recognize the headers inside the script tag as they're not real dom nodes yet so either move them out of the template or initialize footable after the table has rendered data into the dom.

Comment: I think @HelderRoem is on the right track.  Could you post a JSFiddle or Plunk?  That would really help see what is going on.